# DOMXpath & PHP: how to wrap a bunch of <li> inside an <ul>

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath, dom-traversal

I have a html-document with this not-so-nice markup, without the 'ul':

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum...</p>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<div>...</div>
```

I am now trying to "grab" all li-elements and wrap them inside an ul-list which I'd like to place in the same spot, using PHP and DOMXPath. I manage to find and "remove" the li-elements:

```
$elements =  $xpath->query('//li[@class="item"]');

$wrapper = $document->createElement('ul');
foreach($elements as $child) {
    $wrapper->appendChild($child);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to get the ul into the right place - I guess that exactly is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get the `parentNode` of the first `<li>` and then use the `insertBefore` method:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum...</p>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<div>...</div>
HTML;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('//li[@class="item"]');

$wrapper = $doc->createElement('ul');
$elements->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore(
    $wrapper, $elements->item(0)
);

foreach($elements as $child) {
    $wrapper->appendChild($child);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DbLMm)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need. You may need to tweak the XPath query for your real HTML.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$html = <<<EOT
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum...</p>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<li class='item'>...</li>
<li class='item'>last...</li>
<div>...</div>
EOT;

$document->LoadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$elements =  $xpath->query('//li[@class="item"]');

// Saves a reference to the Node that is positioned right after our li's
$ref = $xpath->query('//li[@class="item"][last()]')->item(0)->nextSibling;

$wrapper = $document->createElement('ul');
foreach($elements as $child) {
    $wrapper->appendChild($child);
} 

$ref->parentNode->insertBefore($wrapper, $ref);

echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Running example: https://repl.it/B3UO/24

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't have any chance of knowing exactly which element the one is that comes right befor the li's, like in your example $div = $xpath->query('//div')->item(0);

Comment: As I said, not knowing your document makes it hard to post an answer. You can tweak this part to do something like: `$xpath->query('//li[last()]')->item(0)->next_sibling()`;

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I forgot to mention that these li's can be on a non-specific place, even though they're all following each other. The fix you suggested gave me a 'Call to a member function next_sibling() on null', probably because I have removed the li's without putting them back yet, thus there where no li's, right?

Comment: I updated the answer. You should be fine now. `$ref = $xpath->query('//li[@class="item"][last()]')->item(0)->nextSibling;`

Comment: That worked perfect as far as I have described it. Then again, the li's contain a-tags with attributes (href) - they're gone (the a-tag and the attributes). Any idea how to preserve them?

Comment: I added <a> tags to the markup and it seems to work just fine https://repl.it/B3UO/25

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why this does not work for me though, I just get a "flat" node back. Could you change your example so you'd as well check for the next_sibling()-stuff, not a "hardcoded" div?